# Liouville's equation

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve (or rather show the solution of) Liouville's equation $$\Delta W = -2Ke^{W} $$ for $K=1$ in some simply connected domain $D$. This equation is derived from differential geometry, in the equation for the gaussian curvature given only in the coefficients of the first fundamental form ($E, F$ and $G$) after we put $G=E$ and $F=0$. So basically, if I've understood it correctly so far, we might just aswell find all diffeomorphisms $\Psi: S^{2} \to S^{2}$ such that $\langle \Psi_{u}, \Psi_{u} \rangle = \langle \Psi_{v}, \Psi_{v}\rangle$ and $\langle \Psi_{u}, \Psi_{v} \rangle =0$ and then the function $E = \langle \Psi_{u}, \Psi_{u} \rangle$ would be a solution to Liouville's equation. Equivalently the equation can be written as $$ \frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} = -\frac{1}{2}Ke^{W}$$ for $W = W\left(z, \bar{z}\right)$.

Since we let $K=1$, we can "pretend" that we are on the unit sphere (since locally surfaces with the same constant curvature are isometric (right?)). So the next step which is a previous hint that I've been given is to compute the composition of the stereographic projection with an arbitrary conformal function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ ($\iff \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0 \text{ and } f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$) and then take the composition with the inverse of the stereographic projection so we get a conformal function $$\psi: \sigma^{-1} \circ f \circ \sigma:S^{2} \to S^{2}.$$
I'm using Tapp. Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces and page 175 for the stereographic projection. We simply let $p\in S^{2}$, then for some $\theta$ and $r>0$, $p = \left(r\cos{\theta}, r\sin{\theta},\sqrt{1-r^2}\right)$. Then we use that $r = \frac{4R}{R^{2}+4}$ to get that the stereographic projection is $$\sigma(p) = \sigma\left(\frac{4R}{R^{2}+4}\cos{\theta}, \frac{4R}{R^{2}+4}\sin{\theta}, \sqrt{1-\frac{16R^2}{\left(R^{2}+4\right)^2}}\right)=\left(R\cos{\theta}, R\sin{\theta}\right). $$
Pretending that this point is in $\mathbb{C}$ we can let $\left(R\cos{\theta}, R\sin{\theta}\right) = Re^{i\theta}$. Now I need to take an aribtrary conformal function $f$ with this argument, $f\left(Re^{i\theta}\right)=\dots$? How do I proceed to then also use the inverse stereographic projection of this?

Also, why do we need/want $f$ to be conformal? I have not yet understood that.

Also, the solution is known and it is: $$W\left(z,\bar{z}\right) = \ln{\left(4\frac{\vert \mathrm{d}f(z)/dz \vert^{2}}{\left(1+\vert f(z) \vert^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)}$$ for $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z} \neq 0$ for all $z \in D$ (which ensures that $f$ is conformal) and $f(z)$ has at most simple poles in $D$ (I don't know why we need that).

I would prefer to find a solution using this kind of differential geometry - approach. But any help is appreciated!

Thank you.